# tooltip on image click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have a table with thead and th's. Inside each th I have an image of shape question mark '?'. I want to show a help/tooltip on click of each th's help image. How to do this ?

Please suggest

Comment: What to you want to be shown in the tooltip?

Comment: I want to show for each image a separate static message ....

Comment: http://bonrouge.com/~js_tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many plugins for jquery that will do the work :

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

another plugin I have used:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Here are some tutorials for tooltips:
http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/

Comment: @Evip: are they both same? any other plugin ? Can it be done without plugin using jquery UI

Answer (score 3):

I would use a plugin. [Tooltip](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) is a good one I have used.